# Formatting first/last byte of curve25519 private key?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Can anyone dumb it down for me on why you would need to format the first and last byte of a random number to properly generate a curve25519 private key as noted in 'Computing secret keys' section of http://cr.yp.to/ecdh.html#curve25519-paper.

> **Computing secret keys**. Inside your program, to generate a 32-byte Curve25519 secret key, start by generating 32 secret random bytes from
> a cryptographically safe source: mysecret[0], mysecret[1](http://cr.yp.to/ecdh.html#curve25519-paper), ...,
> mysecret[31]. Then do
>
> ```
>  mysecret[0] &= 248;
>  mysecret[31] &= 127;
>  mysecret[31] |= 64;
> ```

mysecret[0] &= 248 = 0b1111 1000...setting three lsb's to 0 to ensure multiple of 8?
mysecret[31] &= 127 = 0b0111 1111...setting the msb to 0 for?
mysecret[31] |= 64 = 0b0100 0000...setting the second msb to 1 for?

I must be missing some important note on this in [RFC7748](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7748)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87709/76473

Comment: RFC's are the standard, you need to look at papers to get the mathematical background, security proofs etc.

Comment: Yes, thank you that does help. I also see now in section 5 of the RFC where it describes this encoding. Are there any recommended test vectors for curve25519 shared secret calculation?

Comment: Did you see section 6?

Comment: I did, but was thinking there would be more than just a single vector...

Comment: Quite often a single vector is enough, the rest is testing edge cases in your implementation. Testing against a known good application would be an option.