# Does BearSSL Library Support ECC Encryption/Decryption Functionality?

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves, decryption

I'm researching cryptographic libraries for a project I'm working on, and I'm particularly interested in the BearSSL Library due to its lightweight nature. But I'm not sure if it supports ECC (Elliptic Curve Cryptography) encryption/decryption functionality.

Can someone provide information on whether the BearSSL Library includes ECC encryption support or just supports ecc for authentication, and if it does support ecc encryption/decryption, where can I find how to use it?

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,

ikcekis

Comment: ECC encryption is not a thing and our Bear would not do it!. https://bearssl.org/#documentation. Why do you need EC encryption and authentication? May be you need [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme (ECIES)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme#Formal_description_of_ECIES)

Comment: One of the reason is this, even encoding is not perfect. [How to create an EC point from a plaintext message for encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76340/18298)

Answer (score 1):

https://bearssl.org/#documentation

- AES/GCM, AES/CCM, AES/CBC, 3DES/CBC and ChaCha20+Poly1305 encryption algorithms are supported.
- ECDHE (Elliptic Curve Diffie Hellman Ephemeral) is available for key exchange more information about this can be found on: https://www.ecdhe.com/